# Geopaparazzi Export

Tags: gpx

I've been using geopaparazzi to collect some data in the field. During the collection I use the notes option to store some valuable information. But after the export of the data in gpx, there is no tags showing my notes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx
  version="1.0"
  creator="Geopaparazzi - http://www.geopaparazzi.eu"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
<time>2014-04-03T12:18:48Z</time>
<bounds minlat="0.0" minlon="0.0" maxlat="48.786244" maxlon="11.383844"/>
<wpt lat="48.786228" lon="11.38384">
  <ele>419.7365417480469</ele>
  <name>building</name>
  <cmt></cmt>
  <desc></desc>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="48.786244" lon="11.383844">
  <ele>419.5691833496094</ele>
  <name>Sol</name>
  <cmt></cmt>
  <desc></desc>
</wpt>
</gpx>
```

The different waypoints were supposed to get more information. i.e wpt building was supposed to have also height, name, number of floors and so on.

Exporting the data in spatiallite seems not to be supported.

Please, has someone any idea, how can export the data with all the relevant information?

Comment: I´m lookink around how to extract the data via xml or something, because the data are in kml/kmz comment with xml style

Comment: Hi Juan, there is a plugin in QGIS to deal with this issue.

Comment: The only *direct* export from geopaparazzi with all of the form data (I assume from the comment, that you are using forms to add more alphanumeric data) is the KMZ format. That one will insert everything surveyed.

Else, to transform properly in GIS data, the STAGE application will help you converting every form item.
More can be found here: http://www.slideshare.net/silli/2014-10-27foss4gosakageopapworkshop